# Predicting User Intent

Tags: machine-learning, probability, prediction, data-science

I am new to machine learning/data science. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

Given following data from past website visitors:
1. Journey on site: Urls visited and in which order
2. Any comments left on site

Predict the intent of users currently visiting site (using their journey map so far):
1. Give a list of urls they are likely to visit next with % of likelihood
2. Keywords from past users comments that uniquely match the current users journey so far

I am not sure what would be a good/easy approach to get started with to tackel this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straightforward question to answer. It's like asking 'I'm new to medicine, but I'm looking to perform a heart bypass. What methods should I use?'

Depending on your exact data format, and the data itself there may be none or many ways to solve it. Certainly none of which are capable of being relayed in 500 words on SO.

Luckily, 'Data Science' is all about learning by doing, so here's ample resources to find inspiration.

https://www.kaggle.com/wiki/Tutorials

http://datasciencemasters.org/

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html

If you want more specific answers, post your data, and what you have tried, and why you are struggling to make your approach work.

Comment: thanks chris, what I am hoping to get is a possibly specific algorithm/tool/technique that can be used for a problem like this so I can read more into that, but thanks for the links, if I find nothing specific those would be a good starting point.

Comment: I missed it off, but for point two, look at Natural language processing. My first guess for the rest would be some kind of classification algorithm (Look at Niave Bayes, SVM, Random forest classifiers). However, the algorithm is actually one of the easy parts. You need to invest time investigating your data. What features are most predictive? How does the data 'look' (in the n-dimensional sense)? Exploratory Data Analysis is something you should look up - this is always the first stop.